# iOS extension - crash in production

Tags: ios, swift, production, ios-extensions

I have today extension and in production reports, I can see a lot of crashes:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

Backtrace:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1a4043d04 __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:202)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19d1683d0 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1a41b8ac8 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 136 (NSObject.m:140)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1a405a138 ___forwarding___ + 1592 (NSForwarding.m:3578)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1a40c0950 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
5   MyAppWidgetExtension        0x1006f523c MyWidgetProvider.getTimeline(for:in:completion:) + 80 (MyWidget.swift:48)
6   WidgetKit                       0x1b151aa9c closure #1 in IntentTimelineEntryProvider.timeline(for:with:completion:) + 432 (IntentConfiguration.swift:285)
7   WidgetKit                       0x1b143460c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 36 (<compiler-generated>:0)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x1ab509320 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1518)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x1ab50aeac _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x1ab5196a4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928 (queue.c:7794)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x1ab5192f4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44 (queue.c:7954)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x1a40d2c78 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1780)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x1a40b45b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1992 (CFRunLoop.c:3147)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x1a40b943c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
15  Foundation                      0x19e3bf0c4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
16  Foundation                      0x19e3bef58 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 64 (NSRunLoop.m:398)
17  libxpc.dylib                    0x203b75678 _xpc_objc_main + 496 (main.m:246)
18  libxpc.dylib                    0x203b77924 xpc_main + 156 (init.c:1258)
19  Foundation                      0x19e406ac0 -[NSXPCListener resume] + 312 (NSXPCListener.m:460)
20  ExtensionFoundation             0x1b173e658 -[_EXRunningExtension resume] + 204 (EXRunningExtension.m:250)
21  ExtensionFoundation             0x1b173e4f0 -[_EXRunningExtension startWithArguments:count:] + 188 (EXRunningExtension.m:228)
22  ExtensionFoundation             0x1b175e520 EXExtensionMain + 220 (EXExtensionMain.m:31)
23  Foundation                      0x19e44af80 NSExtensionMain + 204 (NSExtensionMain.m:21)
24  dyld                            0x1c3cdfdec start + 2220 (dyldMain.cpp:1165)

Kernel Triage:
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
```

The line with crash is indicated as this:

```
func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> Void) {
        let configurationStep = configuration.step?.step ?? .unknown    <-- there is a crash
        ....
```

ConfigurationIntent is auto generated class

```
@available(iOS 12.0, macOS 11.0, watchOS 5.0, *) @available(tvOS, unavailable)
@objc(ConfigurationIntent)
public class ConfigurationIntent: INIntent {

    @NSManaged public var step: DataStep?
    @NSManaged public var additionalInformation: AdditionalInformation
    @NSManaged public var source: Source
    @NSManaged public var location: InLocation?

}


@available(iOS 12.0, macOS 11.0, watchOS 5.0, *) @available(tvOS, unavailable)
@objc(WeatherStep)
public class DataStep: INObject {

    @available(iOS 13.0, macOS 11.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
    @NSManaged public var step: DataStepType

    override public class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { true }

}
```

And `DataStepType` have custom extension

```
extension DataStepType {
    var apiDataStep: APIDataStep {
        switch self {
        case .daily:
            return APIDataStep.day
        case .threeHours:
            return APIDataStep.threeHours
        default:
            return APIDataStep.hour
        }
    }
}
```

I have no problems in debug and not all users experience this problem. What can be the cause?

Comment: It might be also useful to see the definition of `DataStep`, as the crash can point to the `step?.step` part.

Comment: Also, there are some availability constraints on `ConfigurationIntent`. What OS and the OS version are in the crash report?

Comment: @lazarevzubov Edited the question to add class details, iOS devices, iOS > 12 (mostly 16.5)

Comment: SwiftUI is only available for iOS 13+ and widget kit 14+. If I had to guess based on the stack you are doing something in get timeline background thread that is required to be in a main thread

Comment: did you get anywhere with this? I am seeing quite a similar crash. Crash is when calling the `identifier` property of an Intent Object that's passed to the timeline generator.